# Getting the last selected item in a multiple selection of iconview?

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk

Consider the example below (pygtk 2, python 2), which generates the following GUI:

[image: test.png]

First, click the General tool button to select it, then hold SHIFT, and multi-select the rest; you'll get a printout:

```
selected [(0,)]
selected [(1,), (0,)]
selected [(2,), (1,), (0,)]
selected [(3,), (2,), (1,), (0,)]
```

Now, select the last tool button ("Other") to reset the previous multiselection, then hold SHIFT, and multi-select the others in inverse order; the printout is now:

```
selected [(3,)]
selected [(3,), (2,)]
selected [(3,), (2,), (1,)]
selected [(3,), (2,), (1,), (0,)]
```

As you can see, regardless of the order of multi-selection, the `icon_view.get_selected_items()` is always sorted, so I cannot use it to get information on which item in the multi-selection I've selected last (the "other" in the first case, and the "General" in the second case).

So, how can I get the last selected item in a multi-selection in this case?

The code, `test.py`:

```
# modified from:
# PyGTK FAQ Entry: How can I use the IconView widget?
# http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq19.016.htp

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class PreferencesMgr(gtk.Dialog):
  def __init__(self):
    gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, 'Preferences', None,
           gtk.DIALOG_MODAL | gtk.DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT,
           (gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_OK,
          gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL))
    self.current_frame = None
    self.create_gui()

  def create_gui(self):

    model = gtk.ListStore(str, gtk.gdk.Pixbuf)

    #pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file('images/prefs_general.png')
    #pixbuf = gtk_widget_render_icon( widget, stock_item, size )
    pixbuf = gtk.AboutDialog().render_icon(gtk.STOCK_ABOUT, gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU)
    model.append(['General', pixbuf])

    #pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file('images/prefs_security.png')
    model.append(['Security', pixbuf])
    model.append(['Nothing', pixbuf])
    model.append(['Other', pixbuf])

    self.icon_view = gtk.IconView(model)
    self.icon_view.set_text_column(0)
    self.icon_view.set_pixbuf_column(1)
    self.icon_view.set_orientation(gtk.ORIENTATION_VERTICAL)
    self.icon_view.set_selection_mode(gtk.SELECTION_MULTIPLE)#(gtk.SELECTION_SINGLE)
    self.icon_view.connect('selection-changed', self.on_select, model)
    self.icon_view.set_columns(1)
    self.icon_view.set_item_width(-1)
    self.icon_view.set_size_request(72, -1)

    self.content_box = gtk.HBox(False)
    self.content_box.pack_start(self.icon_view, fill=True, expand=False)
    self.icon_view.select_path((0,)) # select a category, will create frame
    self.show_all()
    self.vbox.pack_start(self.content_box)
    self.resize(640, 480)
    self.show_all()

  def on_select(self, icon_view, model=None):
    selected = icon_view.get_selected_items()
    if len(selected) == 0: return
    print "selected", selected
    i = selected[0][0]
    category = model[i][0]
    if self.current_frame is not None:
      self.content_box.remove(self.current_frame)
      self.current_frame.destroy()
      self.current_frame = None
    if category == 'General':
      self.current_frame = self.create_general_frame()
    elif category == 'Security':
      self.current_frame = self.create_security_frame()
    else:
      self.current_frame = self.create_generic_frame(category)
    self.content_box.pack_end(self.current_frame, fill=True, expand=True)
    self.show_all()

  def create_general_frame(self):
    frame = gtk.Frame('General')
    return frame

  def create_security_frame(self):
    frame = gtk.Frame('Security')
    return frame

  def create_generic_frame(self, instring):
    frame = gtk.Frame(instring)
    return frame

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p = PreferencesMgr()
  p.run()
  p.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just part of the solution:

```
# Add to the PreferencesMgr __init__:
self.prev_sel_set = set()   # Set of elements selected previously
```

In the on_select method add the middle 4 lines::

```
print "selected", selected   # Old code

sel_set = set(selected)
last_selected = sel_set - self.prev_sel_set
self.prev_sel_set = sel_set
print last_selected          # Print last added item(s)

i = selected[0][0]           # Old code
```

This gives you the last icons added to the selection. I don't know if it's correct, because the shift key can add several icons at once. If you multiselect one by one, this will print the single last item. If you add 2 or 3 at once, then all will be printed.